# use one second monitor for two computers

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two computers, A and B, and one keyboard and mouse and monitor connected through a KVM switch to both. I also have a second monitor connected separately to A.

What is the best way to connect this second monitor to both computers?

Comment: Are CPU A and CPU B on the same motherboard? Are they synonyms for PCs? Please edit your question to include more detail as there is not enough information fo form a proper answer.

Comment: The answer I got, referencing an additional KVM, is the answer I was looking for. Thank you @harrymc.

Answer (score 0):

There are not very many solutions. The options I see are:

1. Get a KVM that can share two monitors.
2. Get a second KVM for the additional monitor.

Comment: If my answer has helped fix your problem, please mark it as accepted (tick the V icon).